# Device serial number (using ADB commands)

Tags: adb, imei

I'm using an automation platform that has an ADB session which requires the *device_serial_list*, which is the serial number.
However, if I do `adb get-serialno` I get a different value than the one shown in [this website](https://www.imei.info/)

**Edit:** when you input your IMEI, it shows you several info about your phone and one of them is the Serial Number which is different than the previous one, so I'm not sure what should be the one to use in this case.

**Edit 2:**

[image]

The previous pic comes in a link starting by "https://www.imei.info/check/lg-warranty-checker"

Comment: `adb devices` will display device serialno

Comment: @alecxs You are right but this command will result in *xxxx device* as the output and since OP is automating, *device* will need to be stripped whereas get-serialno only returns the number.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are confusing two different numbers:

- `adb get-serialno` gives you the *serial number* of the device.
- Link in your question is referring to  [IMEI number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) which can be obtained by `adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1`
  (see  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003016) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357619) for more)

Going by the context, you should use the first number (serial number) and not IMEI number.

Both serial and IMEI numbers are usually found in the *about phone* section in device settings.

**Edit:** Post the edit made by OP, I entered my device IMEI number and it returned the following info, only format shared here, not actual digits
 `IMEI.info: TAC: AAAAAA FAC: BB SNR: CCCCCC CD: D` [1]

The serial number you are referring to SNR above is the 6 digit (6 C's) is the [serial number](https://www.imei.info/faq-what-is-serial-number/), which is manufacturer-defined, 
**NOT** the serial number returned by `adb` (verified, adb command returns 8 digit serial number)

So, the answer remains same, use the adb command output

---

Additional Info

[1]: Output in the linked site corresponds to **pre 2004** 
format

> As of 2004, the format of the IMEI is `AA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-D`, although it may not always be displayed this way

(see section - Structure of the IMEI and IMEISV (IMEI software version) in the [IMEI wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity)

Comment: No, but in the website, if you input the IMEI it shows you a Serial Number. I know they are 2 different things :)

Comment: @Natiya in that case, it is best if you post a screenshot. I tried that website and I couldn't get a serial number for the IMEI I used (from google images, a Galaxy S4).

Comment: Natiya 1. Please make it a point to be as clear as possible in the question, so that the answer can be relevant and not end up **wasting time** of the person who  answers. I was tempted to down vote your question on this account but I didn't 2. If you had bothered to read the linked  IMEI wiki, it would have been clear (there's a reason for citing sources) 3. I trust the revised answer makes it clear. If not, ask. @Firelord as FYI since you too have a OnePlus

Comment: I'm afraid the SNR you mentioned in the answer is not the same I'm referring too.  I'll try to add a screenshot

Comment: @Natiya Linked page points to LG devices. There is no page that corresponds to my device  that gives this *extra information*, so I can't check. The SNR number in the screenshot, how is it different from 1. adb result 2.SNR as in my answer. I am asking in terms of number of digits, alpha numeric etc but even if you give you this information, I doubt I can answer for sure because I can't check

Comment: ESN is likely referring to [Electronic Serial Number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_serial_number) which is for CDMA phones and comparable to IMEI number for GSM phones. You can read the linked site. I can't verify for my device from that site. Sorry, I can't help beyond this point